# Stop Facebook from showing the pictures you like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The photos I *like* are showed on my friends' news feed. How do I stop that?

Answer (score 6):

Sharing is the core nature of Facebook and I don't think you can hide it partially, the way you intend to. I don't remember having an option not to show all or some of the likes, or comments, etc. But there is a workaround possible now: with the new version of the privacy settings, you can share only with a subset of friends while hiding your activity from others. But it's all your activity, not just parts of it.

See [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19920/how-to-create-a-restricted-group-in-facebook-that-is-not-public/) question for details of how to exclude some friends from viewing your activity.

Otherwise, just like x3ja said, you would have to stop liking the photos.

Answer (score 1):

I think a "Like" is just like a post/comment, so it's controlled via the Privacy Setting for Posts (*not tested this*). So I think the only way around this is to stop clicking "Like" on the photos...

Answer (score 0):

It shows if your friend has a public profile. If you like a photo of their's or their status it shows on all of your friend's newsfeeds. A way to tell if it is something your friend posts, is there is an icon that looks like a globe meaning it is public.

I always look for this before "liking" anything and encourage others to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

Just like the picture, and then post a pic to show more attivity to help hide liking the picutre. Update your status, anything to kinda hide that.