# How to create a "restricted" group in Facebook that is NOT public?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Is there any way to create a group of people who can't see any posts in my profile *except* for what I *explicitly* share with them, **without** being forced to make those posts public to the entire world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I haven't tested this, but</del> since the new lists feature, you are able to share your statuses with different groups of people.

> **[When I share something, how do I choose who can see it?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=120939471321735)**
>
> Before you post, look at the audience selector. Use the dropdown menu to choose who you want to share a post with.
>
> ...
>
> **Custom** (Includes specific groups, friend lists or people you’ve specified to include or exclude)

Taken from [this help page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=120939471321735).

So,

1. Create your list
2. Go to **Privacy settings**
3. Choose **Custom** as your default option
4. Choose **Friends** from the **Make this visible to** drop-down list
5. Insert the above created list in the **Hide this from** field
6. Click **Save Setting**

[image]

Now the default visibility for your posts will be *Friends **without*** the persons in the above created list (**Custom**), so they will not see your usual posts.

1. To include them also, click on the "audience selector" button (the one at the left of **Post**) and choose **Friends**
2. To post **only** for them, click on the "audience selector" button (the one at the left of **Post**) and:

   1. Click on **See all lists...**
   2. Click on the respective list(s)

[image]

However, please note that the persons in the respective group will see each other's names  if they click on the post's sharing icon.

[image]

Comment: I have tested it and it works as expected. You can also change the permissions later at any point of time.